# Conditional Resample - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a situation where I want to calculate daily spend based on a contract start date, end date, and total spend. The next step is to sum up the daily spend amounts by month. This is quite easy, which I'll show I accomplish later. However, there's another date (`inv date`); if the `start` is before `inv date` then all daily amounts prior to `inv date` should be summed and included in the same period as the `inv date`.

First, the **easy part**.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'start': ['1/1/2018'], 
               'end': ['3/15/2018'], 
               'inv date': ['2/1/2018'],
               'spend': [400]})


         start        end   inv date    spend
0     1/1/2018  3/15/2018   2/1/2018      400
```

Create the range of dates for the contract

```
prd = pd.period_range(df.loc[0, 'start'], df.loc[0, 'end'], freq='D')
prd = pd.Series(1, prd) # empty series to get the number of days in the monthly period
prd = prd.resample('M').size() * (df.loc[0, 'spend'] / prd.resample('M').size().sum())
```

Which gives me the following series: total spend allocated, by month, based on the number of days in the month...so far, so good.

```
prd

2018-01    167.567568
2018-02    151.351351
2018-03     81.081081
Freq: M, dtype: float64
```

**The Hard Part (for me)**

As I mentioned above, based on the `inv date`, the series should actually look like this:

```
2018-01             0 
2018-02    318.918919
2018-03     81.081081
Freq: M, dtype: float64
```

Because, the `inv date` was after the `start` date, so I don't want to add it until after `inv date`. **FYI**: 318 = 167 +  151 (i.e., for the total in 2/2018 above).

Is this possible with `resample`? If not, what's the most efficient way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with `df` and `prd` from the end of your "easy part" section:

```
# Get the inv date as a pandas Timestamp
invdate = pd.to_datetime(df['inv date'])[0]
oneday = pd.offsets.Day(1)
# Pandas slicing includes BOTH endpoints, so we need this one-day 
# offset to get all values strictly before the inv date
prd.loc[invdate] = prd[invdate] + prd[:invdate - oneday].sum()
prd.loc[:invdate - oneday] = 0

# output
2018-01      0.000000
2018-02    318.918919
2018-03     81.081081
Freq: M, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Why doesn't that same slicing work if I create a DataFrame, using prn's index as the DataFrame index? I get an error.

Comment: @RyanErwin, I just tested that out, and everything works as expected. Would you be able to share your code and/or the precise error?

Comment: Also, I may remove this as the answer or change my question. Depending on the dates, your solution doesn't give me what I want. What I need is all periods before inv date +  the current period. Slight modification to your solution.