# Sampling dataframe Considering NaN values+Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like below. I want to do sampling with '3S'
So there are situations where NaN is present. What I was expecting is the data frame should do sampling with '3S' and also if there is any 'NaN' found in between then stop there and start the sampling from that index. I tried using `dataframe.apply`  method to achieve but it looks very complex. Is there any short way to achieve?

```
df.sample(n=3)
```

Code to generate Input:

```
index = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=13, freq='T')
series = pd.DataFrame(range(13), index=index)
print series

series.iloc[4] = 'NaN'
series.iloc[10] = 'NaN'
```

I tried to do sampling but after that there is no clue how to proceed.

```
2015-01-01 00:00:00    0.0
2015-01-01 01:00:00    1.0
2015-01-01 02:00:00    2.0
2015-01-01 03:00:00    2.0
2015-01-01 04:00:00    NaN
2015-01-01 05:00:00    3.0
2015-01-01 06:00:00    4.0
2015-01-01 07:00:00    4.0
2015-01-01 08:00:00    4.0
2015-01-01 09:00:00    NaN
2015-01-01 10:00:00    3.0
2015-01-01 11:00:00    4.0
2015-01-01 12:00:00    4.0
```

The new data frame should sample based on '3S' also take into account of 'NaN' if present and start the sampling from there where 'NaN' records are found.

Expected Output:

```
2015-01-01 02:00:00    2.0 -- Sampling after 3S
2015-01-01 03:00:00    2.0 -- Print because NaN has found in Next
2015-01-01 04:00:00    NaN -- print NaN record
2015-01-01 07:00:00    4.0 -- Sampling after 3S
2015-01-01 08:00:00    4.0 -- Print because NaN has found in Next
2015-01-01 09:00:00    NaN -- print NaN record
2015-01-01 12:00:00    4.0 -- Sampling after 3S
```

Comment: So you want to reset to 0 wherever you see a NaN and resample from there until the next value ?

Comment: Can you let us know how you want your target df to look like ?

Comment: Asimo, You are correct, I want to reset to 0

Comment: Is there a typo in your Expected df ? Why is the df showing 6 am entryafter 9 am entry?

Comment: yes. there is a typo..I will edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
index = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=13, freq='H')
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': range(13)}, index=index)
df.iloc[4, 0] = np.nan
df.iloc[9, 0] = np.nan

print (df)
                      col
2000-01-01 00:00:00   0.0
2000-01-01 01:00:00   1.0
2000-01-01 02:00:00   2.0
2000-01-01 03:00:00   3.0
2000-01-01 04:00:00   NaN
2000-01-01 05:00:00   5.0
2000-01-01 06:00:00   6.0
2000-01-01 07:00:00   7.0
2000-01-01 08:00:00   8.0
2000-01-01 09:00:00   NaN
2000-01-01 10:00:00  10.0
2000-01-01 11:00:00  11.0
2000-01-01 12:00:00  12.0
```

---

```
m = df['col'].isna()
s1 = m.ne(m.shift()).cumsum()
t = pd.Timedelta(2, unit='H')
mask = df.index >= df.groupby(s1)['col'].transform(lambda x: x.index[0]) + t

df1 = df[mask | m]
print (df1)
                      col
2000-01-01 02:00:00   2.0
2000-01-01 03:00:00   3.0
2000-01-01 04:00:00   NaN
2000-01-01 07:00:00   7.0
2000-01-01 08:00:00   8.0
2000-01-01 09:00:00   NaN
2000-01-01 12:00:00  12.0
```

**Explanation**:

1. Create mask for compare missing values by [`Series.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html)
2. Create groups by consecutive values by comparing shifted values with [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) (!=)

---

```
print (s1)
2000-01-01 00:00:00    1
2000-01-01 01:00:00    1
2000-01-01 02:00:00    1
2000-01-01 03:00:00    1
2000-01-01 04:00:00    2
2000-01-01 05:00:00    3
2000-01-01 06:00:00    3
2000-01-01 07:00:00    3
2000-01-01 08:00:00    3
2000-01-01 09:00:00    4
2000-01-01 10:00:00    5
2000-01-01 11:00:00    5
2000-01-01 12:00:00    5
Freq: H, Name: col, dtype: int32
```

3. Get first value of index per groups, add timdelta (for expected output are added 2T) and compare by `DatetimeIndex`
4. Last filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and chained masks by `|` for `bitwise OR`

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to Fill the NAs with 0:

```
df['Col_of_Interest'] = df['Col_of_Interest'].fillna(0)
```

And then have the resampling to be done on the series:
(if datetime is your index)

```
series.resample('30S').asfreq()
```

Comment: Oh your expected df is very different from what i gauged from your question; I'll edit my answer shortly

Comment: Please check the updated question. I have added code on how to generate input Dataframe.

Comment: You may want to refer to this for condition resampling you are trying to dp here..

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48453212/conditional-resample-pandas